# Postgres RIGHT JOIN with custom array

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm using Postgres 9.1 and want to get a result with some blanks where there is no data.  My query looks like the following:

```
SELECT institution_id FROM ... WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
```

The ... is not important to this question, it's just important that it returns a result with the institution_ids in the array (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) and it includes those institutions with no data. Here is an example of the current output:

```
days    treatments    institution_id
266    6996    4
265    5310    1
267    3361    5
260    2809    3
264    5249    7
```

An example of the output I want is:

```
days    treatments    institution_id
266    6996    4
265    5310    1
267    3361    5
260    2809    3
264    5249    7
               9
```

I know I can achieve this by using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT institution_id
       FROM ... 
       WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
     )
RIGHT JOIN generate_series(1,9) ON generate_series = institution_id
WHERE generate_series IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
```

However, this is extra work because generate_series(1,9) creates institution_ids I'm not interested in, it requires that I know the max institution_id a priori, and it introduces an unnecessary WHERE clause.  Ideally I'd like a query like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT institution_id
      FROM ...
      WHERE institution_id IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
     )
RIGHT JOIN (1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9) ON generate_series = institution_id
```

Where `(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)` is just an array that Postgres will use for the JOIN command.  I've also already tried `[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]` and `{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9}` both to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

You may do an OUTER JOIN directly with a list of values, like this:

```
SELECT v.id,tablename.* FROM tablename RIGHT JOIN (values (1),(3),...,(9)) as v(id)
  ON (tablename.field=v.id)
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on an **array** of IDs, you can use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
SELECT i.institution_id, t.*
FROM   unnest('{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9}'::int[]) institution_id
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (institution_id);
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` to the same effect.
Or just:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9}'::int[]) institution_id
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (institution_id);
```

The `USING` clause in the join condition only adds a single instance of `institution_id` to the output columns. `SELECT *` may be exactly what you want. Or not. **If** all other columns of `tbl` can be `NULL` (`institution_id` being the only not-null column), you can't tell the difference now between a missing row and a row of `NULL` values.

To also preserve the order of elements in the input array:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9}'::int[])  WITH ORDINALITY AS i(institution_id, ord)
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (institution_id);
ORDER  BY i.ord;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)